# What choices do we have on Clear resins for DLP?

Tags: dlp

I'm searching for a truly clear DLP resin which can polymerize between 400nm and 405nm.

I found the unpigmented from FunToDo, but it seems to be yellow-clear:

[image]

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:

[image]

Is there any resin out there which costs likely the same (about 50€/liter) which will give results like this?

Answer (score 2):

Formlabs sells a completely clear resin that they've even made simple lenses from, but it's about $150 for a liter. I have no idea how well it would work with your DLP setup. Looks amazing in the pictures though.

MatterHackers sells PhotoCentric UV Firm Clear for $90 for a liter as well. It's not quite as easy finding pictures of this stuff, but from what it looks like, it's still pretty decent. Assuming you've got a UV DLP

Disclaimer, the PhotoCentric stuff says it's a UV resin (10nm to 400nm IIRC) and I have not the slightest clue what Formlabs designs their resin for, so YMMV.